# Не могу сделать миграцию

Tags: django, captcha

Задача, сделать капчу для сайта. Выбор пал на django-simple-captcha 0.5.13
В документации по установке есть пункт сделать миграцию в базу данных после того как подключил капчу в INSTALLED_APPS.
Пытаюсь сделать миграцию и выходит такая вот ошибка **django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__feedback_reviews.email**
Подскажите как быть? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

        #Отзывы
class Reviews(models.Model): 
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=100, db_index=True)
    text = models.TextField("Сообщение", max_length=5000)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from .models import Reviews
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


        #Форма отзывов
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Reviews
        fields = ['text', 'name', 'email']

        widgets = {
            'text': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }


    def clean_email(self):
        new_email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if Reviews.objects.filter(email=new_email).exists():
            raise ValidationError('You cannot reuse the same email')
        return new_email
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic.base import View
from .models import *
from .forms import ReviewForm
from django.conf import settings
from g_recaptcha.validate_recaptcha import validate_captcha

        #Форма отзывов
class Add_Review(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = ReviewForm()
        return render(request, 'reviews.html', context={'form':form})

        #Проверка на валидность
    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = ReviewForm(request.POST)

        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_review = bound_form.save()
            return redirect('detail_review_url')
        return render(request, 'reviews.html', context={'form':bound_form})


def review_detail(request):
    review = Reviews.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'see_reviews.html', context={'review':review})
```

Comment: ошибка кроется в модели review в поле email. Поскольку я не вижу класса модели, то попытаюсь догадаться, что оно у вас не может принимать Null или другими словами пустое значение. поле email является primary key? Если да, то оно не может иметь: (...blank=True,null=True...)

Comment: Добавил информацию. Поле email не должно принимать пустое значение, так как валидация будет происходить по этому полю.

Comment: что вы имеете в виду под словом "валидация"? Поскольку у вас это EmailField, то валидация что это почта будет уже без дополнительных действий. Если вы имеете в виду, что это будет уникальное поле тогда вам нужно установить уникальность unique=True, но если у вас есть уже записи в БД, то могут возникать колизии с ними

Comment: еще момент: какие команды вводите при миграции? python manage.py makemigrations, а затем python manage.py migrate?

Comment: В документации написано, что сразу python manage.py migrate. Я пробовал и так и так. Когда ввожу python manage.py makemigrations то сообщение, что No changes detected. Я не понимаю как мне сделать эту миграцию для капчи  теперь.. Что делать?

Comment: мне кажется, что приложение captcha тут не при чем. Я бы попробовал бы отключить его в settings.py, сделать миграцию без него. А затем по обстоятельствам. Если миграция удалась без него, значит проблема с приложением. Если миграция без приложения не проходит, фиксить модель, а затем подключать captcha